# Intended way to handle asynchronous onClick events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I think another question confirmed that Javascript functions that you provide as an onClick function for a button are run without regards to any other function being run on an interval.

If so, what's the best way to process onClick inputs that touch (erase and/or add things to) arrays and whatnot that the interval function also reads and manipulates?

So far I've been just setting a flag in the onClick function and then reading those flags in the interval function. Even this seems a bit fishy when the onClick function sets multiple flags, since parallel execution could see half the flags set and the other half unset. Is there an intended programming paradigm for this?

If there isn't a good clean way to accomplish this, are there any libraries like jQuery that somehow queue onClick functions so they don't run along functions on an interval?

Comment: `since parallel execution` - javascript doesn't execute anything in parallel - you need to learn about the [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. This is exactly the clarification i was looking for.